# Ranking Poker Hand

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, poker

I'm building a function `PokerHand()` which should take a 5 card hand as a string and score them according to Texas Holdem Rules. I've written the code so that it's first sorted according to rank. So that the hand `const handOne = ('AC 4S 5S 8C AH')` becomes `let sortedHandOne = ["4S", "5S", "8C", "AC", "AH"]` (which works), and then gets splits into an array of rank and corresponding suits (which isn't working). When I run the suitsAndRank function I am expecting `rankArray = ["4", "5", "8", "A", "A"]` and `suitArray = ["C", "C", "H", "S", "S"]` but I get empty arrays. I can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
function PokerHand() {
    //get ranks of hands 

    const handOne = ('AC 4S 5S 8C AH');
    //const handTwo = ('4S 5S 8C AS AD');

    let rankArray = [];
    let suitArray = [];

    // let rankArrayTwo = [];
    // let suitArrayTwo = [];

    const suits = ["C", "D", "H", "S"]
    const ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

    let arrayHandOne = handOne.split(" ");
    //let arrayHandTwo = handTwo.split(" ");

    function sorted() {
    let sortedHand = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayHandOne.length; j++ ) {
            if (ranks[i] === arrayHandOne[j].charAt(0)) {
                sortedHand.push(arrayHandOne[j])
            }
        }   
    }
        return sortedHand;
    }

    console.log(sorted())

    let sortedHandOne = sorted(arrayHandOne);
    //let sortedHandTwo = sortedHand(arrayHandTwo);
    console.log(sortedHandOne)
    function suitAndRank(sortedHandOne) {
        console.log(sorted)
        for (i = 0; i< sortedHandOne.length; i++) {
            let sted = sortedHandOne;
            rankArray.push(sted[i].charAt(0))
            suitArray.push(sted[i].charAt(1)) 
        } 
    }

    console.log(rankArray, suitArray)

    function countSuites(suitArray) {
        let suitCount = {};
        suitArray.forEach(function(x) { suitCount[x] = (suitCount[x] || 0)+1; });
            return suitCount;
    }

    function countRanks(rankArray) {
        let rankCount = {};
        rankArray.forEach(function(x) { rankCount[x] = (rankCount[x] || 0)+1; });
            return rankCount;
    }

    function isFlush() {
        let cS = countSuites(suitArray);
        if(Object.keys(cS).find(key => cS[key] === 5)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function isStraight() {
        let index = ranks.indexOf(rankArray[0])
        let ref = ranks.slice(index, index + 5).join("")
        let section = rankArray.slice(0).join("")
            if (section === "10JQKA" && section === ref) {
                return "ROYALSTRAIGHT";
            } else if (section === "A2345" || section === ref) {
                return "STRAIGHT"; 
            }else {
                return "FALSE";
            }
    }

    function pairs() {
        let rS = countRanks(rankArray)
        return Object.keys(rS).filter((key) => rS[key] === 2).length
    }


    function whichHand() {
        let rS = countRanks(rankArray)
        if (isFlush() === true && isStraight() === "ROYALSTRAIGHT") {
            console.log('Royal Flush')
        } else if (isFlush() === true && isStraight() === "STRAIGHT") {
            console.log("Straight Flush")
        } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 4)) {
            console.log("Four of a Kind")
        } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 3) && pairs() === 2) {
            console.log("Full House")
        } else if (isFlush === true) {
            console.log("Flush")
        } else if (isStraight === "STRAIGHT") {
            console.log("Straight")
        } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 3)) {
            console.log("Three of a Kind")
        } else if (pairs() === 2) {
            console.log("Two Pair")
        }else if(pairs() === 1) {
            console.log("Pair")
        }else {
            console.log('High Card', rankArray[rankArray.length-1])
        }
    }

    return whichHand();
}

// const hands = ['Royal flush', 'Straight flush', 'Four of a kind', 'Full house',
//     'Flush', 'Straight', 'Three of a kind', 'Two pairs', 'Pair', 'High card']  
//     //compare ranks of hands and return results 

PokerHand();
```

Comment: It would likely work better if you don't forget to call `suitAndRank` :P

Comment: Another issue: `function sorted()` has no parameters, it uses the `arrayHandOne` from its parent scope. Better to name it e.g. `arrayHand` inside the function and of course make that a parameter.

Comment: Have i missed something, or don't you need to use `;` anymore!? they are very sporadically used here?

Comment: `sorted()` and `sorted(arrayHandOne)` are two  different functions. You've declared sorted as a function that takes no parameters and instead used the array declared at scope. You'll have to either add the parameter to the function or call it as such `let sortedHandOne = sorted();` and as @Amadan already suggested, call  `suitAndRank`.

Comment: @Stender: JavaScript does not require semicolons due to ASI (automatic semicolon insertion), however relying on it can cause some insidious bugs in certain contexts, so most style guides suggest keeping semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found your problem eventually. The code is changed to give you `rankArray` and `suitArray`. There are two issues:

1. You didn't call the function `suitAndRank(sortedHandOne);`
2. There were two issues with your code in the final `whichHand()` function where you didn't put parenthesis.

See the completed code below with output:

```js
function PokerHand() {
  //get ranks of hands

  const handOne = "AC 4S 5S 8C AH";
  //const handTwo = ('4S 5S 8C AS AD');

  let rankArray = [];
  let suitArray = [];

  // let rankArrayTwo = [];
  // let suitArrayTwo = [];

  const suits = ["C", "D", "H", "S"];
  const ranks = [
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "J",
    "Q",
    "K",
    "A"
  ];

  let arrayHandOne = handOne.split(" ");
  //let arrayHandTwo = handTwo.split(" ");

  function sorted() {
    let sortedHand = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arrayHandOne.length; j++) {
        if (ranks[i] === arrayHandOne[j].charAt(0)) {
          sortedHand.push(arrayHandOne[j]);
        }
      }
    }
    return sortedHand;
  }

  console.log(sorted());

  let sortedHandOne = sorted(arrayHandOne);
  //let sortedHandTwo = sortedHand(arrayHandTwo);
  console.log(sortedHandOne);
  function suitAndRank(sortedHandOne) {
    console.log(sorted);
    for (let i = 0; i < sortedHandOne.length; i++) {
      let sted = sortedHandOne;
      rankArray.push(sted[i].charAt(0));
      suitArray.push(sted[i].charAt(1));
    }
  }

  suitAndRank(sortedHandOne);

  console.log(rankArray, suitArray);

  function countSuites(suitArray) {
    let suitCount = {};
    suitArray.forEach(function(x) {
      suitCount[x] = (suitCount[x] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return suitCount;
  }

  function countRanks(rankArray) {
    let rankCount = {};
    rankArray.forEach(function(x) {
      rankCount[x] = (rankCount[x] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return rankCount;
  }

  function isFlush() {
    let cS = countSuites(suitArray);
    if (Object.keys(cS).find(key => cS[key] === 5)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function isStraight() {
    let index = ranks.indexOf(rankArray[0]);
    let ref = ranks.slice(index, index + 5).join("");
    let section = rankArray.slice(0).join("");
    if (section === "10JQKA" && section === ref) {
      return "ROYALSTRAIGHT";
    } else if (section === "A2345" || section === ref) {
      return "STRAIGHT";
    } else {
      return "FALSE";
    }
  }

  function pairs() {
    let rS = countRanks(rankArray);
    return Object.keys(rS).filter(key => rS[key] === 2).length;
  }

  function whichHand() {
    let rS = countRanks(rankArray);
    if (isFlush() === true && isStraight() === "ROYALSTRAIGHT") {
      console.log("Royal Flush");
    } else if (isFlush() === true && isStraight() === "STRAIGHT") {
      console.log("Straight Flush");
    } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 4)) {
      console.log("Four of a Kind");
    } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 3) && pairs() === 1) {
      console.log("Full House");
    } else if (isFlush() /*First issue*/ === true) {
      console.log("Flush");
    } else if (isStraight() /*Second issue*/ === "STRAIGHT") {
      console.log("Straight");
    } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 3)) {
      console.log("Three of a Kind");
    } else if (pairs() === 2) {
      console.log("Two Pair");
    } else if (pairs() === 1) {
      console.log("Pair");
    } else {
      console.log("High Card", rankArray[rankArray.length - 1]);
    }
  }

  return whichHand();
}

// const hands = ['Royal flush', 'Straight flush', 'Four of a kind', 'Full house',
//     'Flush', 'Straight', 'Three of a kind', 'Two pairs', 'Pair', 'High card']
//     //compare ranks of hands and return results

PokerHand();
```

Comment: Also found an issue with your full house checking. The code should look as follows when checking for full house:

Comment: It should be one pair not two pairs and a three of a kind

Comment: else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 3) && pairs() === 1) {
      console.log("Full House");
    }

Comment: Please add such additions to the answer ifself, not to the comment section.

Comment: Doesn't work with rank 10 (10A, 10K, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Find the corrected code below, the problems are described in the comments

```
function PokerHand() {
//get ranks of hands 

const handOne = ('AC 4S 5S 8C AH');
//const handTwo = ('4S 5S 8C AS AD');

let rankArray = [];
let suitArray = [];

// let rankArrayTwo = [];
// let suitArrayTwo = [];

const suits = ["C", "D", "H", "S"]
const ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

let arrayHandOne = handOne.split(" ");
//let arrayHandTwo = handTwo.split(" ");

function sorted(arrayHand) { // added the parameter required
    let sortedHand = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayHand.length; j++ ) { 
            if (ranks[i] === arrayHand[j].charAt(0)) {
                sortedHand.push(arrayHand[j])
            }
        }   
    }
    return sortedHand;
}


let sortedHandOne = sorted(arrayHandOne); // sorted() did not take any parameters before
//let sortedHandTwo = sorted(arrayHandTwo);
function suitAndRank(sortedHand) { // changed the param name
    for (i = 0; i< sortedHand.length; i++) { // removed sted as is not really needed
        rankArray.push(sortedHand[i].charAt(0))
        suitArray.push(sortedHand[i].charAt(1)) 
    } 
}

suitAndRank(sortedHandOne); // was not being called before
// suitAndRank(sortedHandTwo);

function countSuites(suitArray) {
    let suitCount = {};
    suitArray.forEach(function(x) { suitCount[x] = (suitCount[x] || 0)+1; });
        return suitCount;
}

function countRanks(rankArray) {
    let rankCount = {};
    rankArray.forEach(function(x) { rankCount[x] = (rankCount[x] || 0)+1; });
        return rankCount;
}

function isFlush() {
    let cS = countSuites(suitArray);
    if(Object.keys(cS).find(key => cS[key] === 5)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function isStraight() {
    let index = ranks.indexOf(rankArray[0])
    let ref = ranks.slice(index, index + 5).join("")
    let section = rankArray.slice(0).join("")
        if (section === "10JQKA" && section === ref) {
            return "ROYALSTRAIGHT";
        } else if (section === "A2345" || section === ref) {
            return "STRAIGHT"; 
        }else {
            return "FALSE";
        }
}

function pairs() {
    let rS = countRanks(rankArray)
    return Object.keys(rS).filter((key) => rS[key] === 2).length
}


function whichHand() {
    let rS = countRanks(rankArray)
    if (isFlush() === true && isStraight() === "ROYALSTRAIGHT") {
        console.log('Royal Flush')
    } else if (isFlush() === true && isStraight() === "STRAIGHT") {
        console.log("Straight Flush")
    } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 4)) {
        console.log("Four of a Kind")
    } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 3) && pairs() === 2) {
        console.log("Full House")
    } else if (isFlush() === true) { // problem here as isFlush is a function not a variable, otherwise it returns undefined
        console.log("Flush")
    } else if (isStraight() === "STRAIGHT") { // problem again, isStraight is a function too so it should be isStraight() instead of isStraight, otherwise it returns undefined
        console.log("Straight")
    } else if (Object.keys(rS).find(key => rS[key] === 3)) {
        console.log("Three of a Kind")
    } else if (pairs() === 2) {
        console.log("Two Pair")
    }else if(pairs() === 1) {
        console.log("Pair")
    }else {
        console.log('High Card', rankArray[rankArray.length-1])
    }
}

  return whichHand();
}

// const hands = ['Royal flush', 'Straight flush', 'Four of a kind', 'Full house',
//     'Flush', 'Straight', 'Three of a kind', 'Two pairs', 'Pair', 'High card']  
//     //compare ranks of hands and return results 

PokerHand();
```